# Laravel - Which user creates log files

Tags: mysql, laravel, logging, permissions

My issue is I've a laravel web application and  in the storage folder I'm logging the slow SQL queries, but they do not appear. In laravel.log I can see the following error:

```
[2019-02-22 07:23:21] dev.ERROR: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/com.mywebsite/storage/logs/sql/2019-02-22-slow-log.sql): failed to open stream: Permission denied {"userId":40,"email":"a.user@somewhere.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/var/www/html/com.mywebsite/storage/logs/sql/2019-02-22-slow-log.sql): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/html/com.mywebsite/vendor/mnabialek/laravel-sql-logger/src/SqlLogger.php:179)
```

I'm running this on CentOS 7 linux with NginX and PHP-FPM. Both of them runnin with user called `web` and the permissions on all the files and folders is `web:web`. However, I saw one slow-query log file, with the permission `root:web`. What gives?

Comment: Slow query logs are generated by MySQL.

Comment: So the file is made by the user running mysql and that is root, ok. But then why is the `web` user trying to write in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yeah! I have found the issue. One of my former sys.operators wrote the cronjob and I didn't pay attention. He wrote it for the sudo user and not the web user. It was a job to run certain PHP commands. That is why the log file appeared with root permissions, but later on, the laravel application was unable to write it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Very good: problem solved. Please consider accepting the answer